# create array on basis of object's child

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am have array like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "62434e4c52a870a3840f40fd",
    "Nome": [
      {
        "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a",
        "value": "Oo",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "Peso": [
      {
        "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182",
        "value": "554",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": [
      {
        "value": "29/03/2022 03:22:02"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62449de6ed196e40cb4309ae",
    "Nome": [
      {
        "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a",
        "value": "Ssg",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "Peso": [
      {
        "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182",
        "value": "255",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": [
      {
        "value": "29/03/2022 03:23:26"
      }
    ]
  },
],
```

What I'm having trouble with is loop between each object example `Nome`, `Peso` the names of these arrays are dynamic and do not have a static name!

Example of what I'm thinking:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "62434e4c52a870a3840f40fd",
    "Nome": "Oo",
    "Peso": "554",
    "createdAt": "29/03/2022 03:22:02"
  },
  {
    "_id": "62449de6ed196e40cb4309ae",
    "Nome": "Ssg",
    "Peso": "255",
    "createdAt": "29/03/2022 03:23:26"
  }
],
```

Thanks for help :D

Comment: `Peso` and `Nome` are arrays, how do you pick values? @Gabriel

Comment: @NickVu I was trying with `Object.keys().map()` and after get value of field

Comment: I meant `Peso` have multiple values because they're arrays, how do you can get a single value from there? You get the first value always? @Gabriel

Comment: @NickVu Yes I always get first value this array represents a field of a form that was saved

Comment: Now you already had 3 good answers! :D. By the way, next time you should have clearer inputs/outputs. Otherwise, all answers will be based on assumptions @Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If considering those dynamic keys will have array then try below code.

```js
const data = [{
    "_id": "62434e4c52a870a3840f40fd",
    "Nome": [{
      "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a",
      "value": "Oo",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
    }],
    "Peso": [{
      "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182",
      "value": "554",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
    }],
    "createdAt": [{
      "value": "29/03/2022 03:22:02"
    }]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62449de6ed196e40cb4309ae",
    "Nome": [{
      "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a",
      "value": "Ssg",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
    }],
    "Peso": [{
      "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182",
      "value": "255",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
    }],
    "createdAt": [{
      "value": "29/03/2022 03:23:26"
    }]
  },
];

data.map(d => {
  Object.keys(d).forEach(k => {
    if (Array.isArray(d[k]) && d[k].length > 0)
      d[k] = d[k][0].value;
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Yeahh I will test and post results

Comment: Good approach! Are you better off using `.forEach` instead of `.map` since you do not have a return statement?

Comment: Yes i am remade with forEach but thanks for help ^^ it works here! i am made rep+ for you

Answer (score 2):

If each `Nome`, `Peso`, `createdAt` property array always has one element, then you can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follow:

```js
const input = [ { "_id": "62434e4c52a870a3840f40fd", "Nome": [ { "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a", "value": "Oo", "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z" } ], "Peso": [ { "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182", "value": "554", "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z" } ], "createdAt": [ { "value": "29/03/2022 03:22:02" } ] }, { "_id": "62449de6ed196e40cb4309ae", "Nome": [ { "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a", "value": "Ssg", "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z" } ], "Peso": [ { "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182", "value": "255", "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z" } ], "createdAt": [ { "value": "29/03/2022 03:23:26" } ] } ];

const output = input.map(({_id,...rest}) => ({
    _id,
    ...Object.fromEntries( 
        Object.entries(rest).map(([k,v]) => [k,v[0].value])
    )
}));

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Almost there the object keys are dynamic not static

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that; will rework it. Just to be clear are `_id` and `createdAt` are not dynamic, but everything else is, right? Check the updated version.

Comment: Thanks for your time Peter i am made rep+ for you

Answer (score 1):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const transformArr = arr => (
  arr.map(obj => ({
    ...Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && v.length > 0 &&
            Array.isArray(v) &&
            "value" in v[0]
          ) {
          return [k, v[0].value]
        } else {
          return [k, v]
        }
      })
    )
  }))
);

const origArr = [
  {
    "_id": "62434e4c52a870a3840f40fd",
    "Nome": [
      {
        "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a",
        "value": "Oo",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "Peso": [
      {
        "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182",
        "value": "554",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": [
      {
        "value": "29/03/2022 03:22:02"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62449de6ed196e40cb4309ae",
    "Nome": [
      {
        "_id": "61f76c3c7a308dd136f1d33a",
        "value": "Ssg",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "Peso": [
      {
        "_id": "61f92ec87a308dd136c0e182",
        "value": "255",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": [
      {
        "value": "29/03/2022 03:23:26"
      }
    ]
  },
];

console.log(transformArr(origArr));
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over the array
- Use `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` to extract key-value `[k, v]`pairs (as arrays) and then re-create (key-value pairs array back into an) object
- Check if `v` is an array and that it has an element at index-0 with a prop `value`
- If yes, then transform it to show only the `value` (of index-0 element)
- Otherwise, just return `v` as-is

**Constraint**

If the inner-array (for "Nome", "Peso" or other "dynamic keys") has more than one element only the `value` from index-0 element will be considered.

**NOTE**

This solution does not mutate the original-array. It creates a new copy & if needed this may be re-assigned to the original-array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the resolution and explanation, this logic will still grow to other arrays that will be created within this object but for now this logic is enough without a doubt I will use your explanation to evolve this logic for more children fields ^^

Comment: Please just note that this one & the answer by PeterKA - these do not mutate / change the existing array. Both these will create new arrays. In case of this solution, as long as these dynamic keys have a value which is an array, and has at least 1 element and the element at index-0 has a prop `value`, that value should get picked-up. +1 for the question.